# How can i test a materialized icon using protractor?

Tags: protractor, e2e-testing

I want to test a materialized icon using protractor but it wasn't successful using button text. Is there any possible solution for test it?

this is the code that I want to test:

```
<i class="material-icons">add</i>
```

Comment: how do you want to test it? what assertion you want to make?

Comment: you want to test the class attribute value ?

Comment: I want to add an option to a post using add button, which is specified by a materialized icon. So, I want to test that feature is working or not. <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="action">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </button>

Answer (score 0):

Try the below one

```
const add = element(by.cssContainingText('i.material-icons','add'));
```